# Derivative of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I'm reading a engeneering book (Turbulent Flow - Pope) and it isn't very rigorous.

Let $X(t)$ be a casual variable, for every fixed $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

How can we define the derivative with respect to $t$?

What are the assumptions that allow $\partial_t\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\partial_tX]$

Comment: Note that you can also write this as $$∂_t\int_{\Omega}X(t,\omega)dP(\omega)=\int_{\Omega}∂_tX(t,\omega)dP(\omega),$$ so that this amount to some limit-integral exchange theorem in the theory of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Ok ok, i was confused for PDF and CDF... in this way it's more natural and clear. Thank you.